# SurrealDB - How to use Record ID as LET defined variable

Tags: surrealdb

I want to give the record id as a LET defined variable like this:

```
LET $item_id = 1;

SELECT ->Contain->Ingredient as ingredients FROM Product:$barcode;
```

But it doesn't work.

I also tried where clause but it didn't work either:

```
SELECT ->Contain->Ingredient as ingredients FROM Product WHERE Product.id = $barcode
```

---

How to use `table:id` format with `LET` defined variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this:

```
LET $id = 1;
LET $product_thing = type::thing("Product", $id);
```

Then I used it like this:

```
// Get ingredients of a product:
SELECT ->Contain->Ingredient as ingredients FROM $product_thing;
```